# Issue in Symfony when setting login path

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I am trying to set up users in a project, but I receive errors because of the login path. It looks like an issue with spaces, but I tried with a php file and the error is the same.

> FileLoaderLoadException: The routing file
>   "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Symfony/app/config/routing.yml" contains
>   unsupported keys for "login": "pattern". Expected one of: "resource",
>   "type", "prefix", "path", "host", "schemes", "methods", "defaults",
>   "requirements", "options", "condition" in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Symfony/app/config/routing.yml (which is
>   being imported from
>   "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Symfony/app/config/routing_dev.yml").

The code in app/config was :

```
login:
    pattern:    /login
    defaults:   { _controller: OCUserBundle:Security:login }
```

---

EDIT:
So I get the same error with a new project.
Here is what I am doing :
-Create 2 bundles (MGeneralBundle, MUserBundle) inside "Me", the namespace of my project.
-In app/config/routing.yml:

```
me_m_general:
    resource: "@MeMGeneralBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /

login:
     path:   /login
     defaults: { _controller: MeMUserBundle:Security:login}

login_check:
    path:    /login_check

logout:
    path:    /logout
```

And in app/config/security.yml:

```
security:
    in_memory:
        memory: ~
firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main_login:
    # Cette expression régulière permet de prendre /login (mais pas /login_check !)
        pattern:   ^/login$
        anonymous: true
    main:
        pattern:   ^/
        anonymous: false
        provider:  in_memory
        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login_check
        logout:
            path:   logout
            target: /
```

And the controller for the login, with the routing.yml in the UserBundle :

```
me_home:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: MeMUserBundle:Default:index }



<?php

namespace Me\MUserBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;

class SecurityController extends Controller
{
    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {
      if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')) {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('me_home');
      }
      $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');
      return $this->render('MeMUserBundle:Security:login.html.twig', array(
        'last_username' => $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername(),
        'error'         => $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError(),
      ));
    }
}
```

The error is :

> You have requested a non-existent service "security.context".

at : http://localhost:8888/Me/web/app_dev.php/login .

I don't know how to debug this.

Comment: The error is pretty straight-forward. `pattern` is deprecated and removed for quite a while - simply replace it with `path`.

Comment: You're welcome, @Paul. Also, keep in mind that you're most likely reading an older version of the documentation. `security.context` has also been renamed since version 2.6.

Comment: @Artamiel ok thanks, I created a new project, but the error is the same. I explain in details what I am doing in the edit.

Comment: Like @Artamiel said the `security.context`  service [was deprecated in Symfony 2.6](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-security-component-improvements) and therefore was removed in Symfony 3.0. You need to user either the `security.token_storage`  or `security.authorization_checker`  service depending on what you want to do.

Comment: @xabbuh thanks, yes I did not understand perfectly at first the way to solve it, it works fine now, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `security.context` service [was deprecated in 2.6](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-security-component-improvements) and removed entirely in 3.0.  You want to use `security.authorization_checker` instead:

```
 if ($this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')) {
```

In fact, Symfony 2.6 also [introduced new controller shortcuts](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-new-shortcut-methods-for-controllers) so you don't even have to explicitly call that service.  This looks cleaner and will work just as well in your controller:

```
if ($this->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')) {
```